# Matching in sequential order

Tags: bash, grep

I have to match multiple strings in a file using `grep` command, following is the command i am using:

```
grep -e 'str1' -e 'str2' file.log
```

I need all the lines containing `str1` and `str2` but in the same order as they are in the file.

Does `grep` **guarantees** that matching order will be same as order of occurrence of string in file? or it can shuffle the matching order [can happen if it uses multiple threads]

Answer (score 3):

[`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) processes input files as streams (and is IO-bound); output lines are always in the same order as the input lines, regardless of how many patterns are provided.

It is not required to evaluate the patterns themselves in any particular order, which may be the source of your confusion, but it always operates linewise.